# Pandas indexing and what .index does

Tags: python, pandas

I *think* this is a fairly simple question, but can't answer it.

What does .index do in this bit of code:

```
df.drop(df[df['Quantity'] == 0].index).rename(columns={'Weight': 'Weight (oz.)'}))
```

If I understand things,

```
[df['Quantity'] == 0]
```

returns a boolean mask, which is then masked against the dataframe df, and an object reference is returned. Is that right? Why do you need the `.index`?

Comment: cause you want to drop the index when the bool is True , drop only take index (or columns when axis =1 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df[df['Quantity'] == 0]` find rows where `Quantity` is 0

`df[df['Quantity'] == 0].index` index of rows where `Quantity` is 0

`df.drop(df[df['Quantity'] == 0].index)` drop the rows using these indexes.

Comment: What is the difference between finding rows and indexes of rows? Surely when you "find rows" you are getting the indexes?

Comment: yes but then you want to drop the rows for which you need index. So you basically take the index out of the rows that you found to give it to the drop function.